# How to copy every row of one matrix into every other row of another matrix using broadcasting?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, array-broadcasting

if I have the following matrices:

```
a = np.array([['A'], ['B'], ['C']])
b = np.array([['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0']])
```

and I want to get the following:

```
c = np.array([['A'], ['0'], ['B'], ['0'], ['C'], ['0']])
```

Is there a way to get c using some type of numpy broadcast/vectorized solution instead of a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For in-situ edit in `b` -

```
b[::2] = a
```

To make those changes in a new array, make a copy and edit -

```
c = b.copy()
c[::2] = a
```

Comment: The step here is really what makes this an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Voila:

```
c = np.reshape(b, (3, 2, 1))
c[:,0]=a
c.shape=6,1
c
array([['A'],
       ['0'],
       ['B'],
       ['0'],
       ['C'],
       ['0']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: ah perfect.  I didn't realize you could use the splice referencing on the left side.  thanks!

Comment: @dranobob Yes, that is very useful, indeed.